# How to keep a Slack channel up-to-date in a 3rd party app?

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I have been playing around with slack API lately, and I came up with one demo project where I'm having some kind of a chat widget, within that a dropdown on the **header** populated with channel list(through channels.list API call), by selecting one of it, the channels.history will be called to populate the widget **body**, and down below on **footer** a text box and send button to post a new message to slack.. NOW, to keep the widget's body up to date, i)I had to make channels.history rest call periodically(if in case anyone's sending messages on the SLACK app) And Also ii)I had made a rest call when the user sends a message from this widget's text box.

My question now is: How do I skip making this periodic call(because I'm getting 429 warning) instead to have any logic implemented that would trigger the channels.history call only when a new message arrives on slack side and not periodically. or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to keep a copy of current messages from a channel up-to-date in a 3rd party app is to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api). You subscribe to the [messages event](https://api.slack.com/events/message) and whenever a new message is posted, Slack will send you a request, which includes the full message. This also works for "complex" messages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with the Slack API but I found this: [real time messaging APIs](https://api.slack.com/rtm).

Since it uses websockets, I assume that you can connect and receive all the emitted messages without having to request periodically for that info. You have to change your app to work with websockets instead for periodic HTTP calls, though.

Comment: thanks, but actually it doesn't support complex messages such as having an attachments,etc

Comment: This may be a bit far-fetched but what if you use the real-time messaging API to keep the history updated but using the web API to send complex messages?